# Power Apps Error while uploading solution to a new env. "The dependent component Attribute (Id=stageid) does not exist."

Tags: dependencies, powerapps, pid

Im currently facing an error within Power Apps.

I'm trying to upload a solution to a new environment. The following error occured:

> "The dependent component Attribute (Id=stageid) does not exist. Failure trying to associate it with ProcessTrigger (Id=3156a7ac-0000-ee11-a569-00224874d224) as a dependency. Missing dependency lookup type = AttributeNameLookup."

I guess it has something to do with the legacy topic described here: https://blog.thenetw.org/2022/03/09/solution-import-error-processid-does-not-exist/

How can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance!